# Why these two c++ functions performance differ

Tags: c++, function, performance

I was doing `leetcode 834`. Sum of Distances in Tree, and I figure a way to solve it with two `dfs`.
But, the first solution received tle when experienced a test set of 10000 nodes. After seeing the answer, I did some simple changes and the answer was accepted.

I don't know why these two functions perform so differently since they are all `O(n)`.

The dfs function is aimed to calculate how many nodes are there under node 'current' and store them in an array 'child'. 'tree' is a 2D vector that contains the edges of the tree in list structure.

old function which received tle:

```
int dfs(vector <vector <int>> tree, int previous, int current)
    {
        int s = tree[current].size();
        int r = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s; ++i){
            if (tree[current][i] == previous) continue;
            r += dfs(tree, current, tree[current][i]);
        }
        child[current] = r;
        d_root += r;
        return r + 1;
    }
```

new function that is accepted:

```
void dfs(int previous, int current)
    {
        int s = tree[current].size();
        int r = 0;
        for (auto& a : tree[current]){
            if (a == previous) continue;
            dfs(current, a);
            r += child[a] + 1;
        }
        child[current] = r;
        d_root += r;
    }
```

Comment: Simply ignore the d_root, it has nothing to do with these functions

Comment: Read about passing by value vs passing by reference. I would suggest investing some money and time into a good introductory C++ [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) before solving random coding exercises on random websites.

Comment: Your first copies the entire `tree` on every recursion.

Comment: @molbdnilo, got it, just add a & and it passed, thanks

Comment: @Evg, I have learned these..... Somehow forgot when coding, anyway, thanks

Comment: @RafaelDD `tle` -- When describing the issue, please don't use abbreviations and acronyms that other C++ programmers know nothing about.  Explicitly state what "tle" means or stands for.  Contrary to what you may believe, most C++ programmers do not go to those "online coding" sites and thus do not know the lingo being used there.

Comment: @molbdnilo not just that, it also shadows the other `tree` that must exist up some scope for the second to work.